# Pull up setting via GPIO on rasperry PI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I need many I2C busses on a rasperry PI so I wrote my own I2C controler using usual GPIOs.

It works when using BCM GPIO 2 and 3, but not other GPIOs.
GPIO 2 and 3 are pulled up to VCC via 1.8KOhm resistor according to the [schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3b_1p2_reduced.pdf).

I wonder why this pull-up resistor is needed, as the GPIOs can be pulled up internally in the BCM (not sure about the resistor value then, maybe it is regarded as too weak for I2C)... Anyway...

When using `Rpi.GPIO`, this "software" pull up should be controled with the following statement:

```
GPIO.setup(<gpio_pin>, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
```

So I wrote the following test code to test things:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
gpios= [3,5,29,31] #board numbering (2,3,5,6 in BCM)

GPIO.setup(gpios, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

for gpio in gpios:  #test pin for pin
    print(">>>>> ", gpio)
    GPIO.setup(gpio, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    res= GPIO.input(gpio)
    print res
```

Which returns

```
./r:15: RuntimeWarning: A physical pull up resistor is fitted on this channel!
  GPIO.setup(gpios, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
('>>>>> ', 3)
./r:18: RuntimeWarning: A physical pull up resistor is fitted on this channel!
  GPIO.setup(gpio, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
1
('>>>>> ', 5)
1
('>>>>> ', 29)
0
('>>>>> ', 31)
0
```

Nothing is connected to any pin yet, so there is nothing pulling anything down.

Strangely, I got the warning for board pin 3 but not 5, despite both being pulled up externally(?).

But more to the point, the above result tells me that my software controlled pull-up failed. I should be getting '1' on all four GPIOs.

Did I misunderstood what Rpi.GPIO is doing?

Comment: It seems about pin control. In case you are running Linux, the bitbanging I²C driver is already there: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-gpio.c.

Comment: yes, I am running linux. and I know the I2C driver exists. But not sure what pins it can run against ( I need many I2c busses), and I want full control over what I do as the chips I am connected to are not fully standard. Having said that, the comment on line 35 in the driver code really raise the same kind of question: what pin can be pulled-up via SW, and how (e.g. via python GPIO)...so the question remains

Comment: How I see it: you take a driver. Then look into documentation for the board and realize what pins can be used. All pairs of such pins can be described in Device Tree as I2C controllers. Also I highly recommend not to use non-standard libraries for GPIO. There is an official one that called `libgpiod` (it has python bindings). And for the record, I don’t think this board is able to service more than two of such bit banging i2c busses, I would recommend to find some kind of USB-2-i2c adapters.

Comment: RPi.GPIO is a bit old fashion but pretty standard to access the PI GPIO pins, as far as I understand. As my question states, it includes some parameter to set pull-up or pull-down... at least as I understand. My question remains: Why can't I use the built-in SW controlled pull up to perform i2c on any GPIO? -or what is wrong in my code. I'd like to understand the problem more than anything else. I guess I can fix it my soldering external pull-up resistor. but it is not my point. My question is regarding the usage of SW controlled pull-up and their interfaces (preferably from python GPIO).

Comment: Built-in pull up / pull down is usually quite weak. I²C relies on the good sharp signal form which is highly depends on PCB and type and amount of devices connected to the bus. It's not SW question, try electric engineering site on StackExchange for this. (I think there are a lot of answers and better explanations already there)

Comment: If you still want to handle the internal bias settings, read how it should be done (usually via Device Tree). RPi GPIO library is a **non-standard**, sorry. It is a particular library developed only for one board and has nothing to do with real generic code.